# ActiveRecord with ORMLite

Tags: android, database, dao

I really like the idea of active record and Im going to implement the following design:
All concrete models extends abstract model, which have basic CRUD operations.

Here is the sample save function on model:

```
public void save(){
    try {
        getDao().createOrUpdate(this);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and here is getDao():

```
private static Dao<Model, Integer> getDao(Context context){
    Dao<Model, Integer> result = null;

    DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    try {
        result = dbHelper.getDao(Model.class);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       

    return result;
}
```

As you can see I have Model.class. Are there any other options or patterns to implement the following design, except passing a Class to getDao function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not make `getDao` method static and then:

```
result = dbHelper.getDao(getClass());
```

Edit:

In that case, you will have to somehow tell the getDao method what dao to get. You could use something like:

```
private static <T> Dao getDao(Context context, T object){
    try {
        return new DatabaseHelper(context).getDao(object.getClass());
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: If it's not a static, than I can't use it for getAll function(static).

Comment: Ok, let me do some other change then :)